# "locked onto to" vs "locked onto"

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

> Before Lieutenant Tillis could give him instructions, Oscar had
> already locked onto to the next set of cars...

The Cyber Shadow - Page 134
Vincent Lopez
Found inside – Page 134
https://www.google.com/books/edition/The_Cyber_Shadow/6ny7DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22locked+onto+to%22&pg=PA134&printsec=frontcover

Is "locked onto" and "locked onto to" the same thing? I am not sure why I see this construction often. It seems to be ungrammatical to me.

Comment: ...you have found another typo. Congratulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Locked onto to" is just a mistake. The writer meant simply "locked onto".